# Python csv list

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file that I process this way. The csv containing just numbers is such:

1, 5, 6, 8, 45, 56

2, 6, 34, 42, 56, 98

1, 5, 6, 8, 45, 56

...

```
import csv

numbers = []

with open('example.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        numbers.append(row)        
               
print(numbers)
```

output:

```
[[1, 5, 6, 8, 45, 56], [2, 6, 34, 42, 56, 98], [1, 5, 6, 8, 45, 56]]
```

How can I make it print the most frequently occurring lists?
For example: 1, 5, 6, 8, 45, 56 2 times in list?

Comment: using the ```.count()``` method perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Counter` class from `collections`.  It can't take lists of lists directly, but by converting the inner lists to tuples you can count them:

```
from collections import Counter

lst = [[1, 5, 6, 8, 45, 56], [2, 6, 34, 42, 56, 98], [1, 5, 6, 8, 45, 56]]
Counter(tuple(i) for i in lst).most_common(1)
```

yields the most common list and how many times it occured:

```
[((1, 5, 6, 8, 45, 56), 2)]
```

Counter have several other useful functions when it comes to counting, and it is very performant.

[The docs for Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

Answer (score 0):

Use count row when you are appending numbers

```
import csv

numbers = []
max_occurance_count=0

with open('example.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        numbers.append(row)        
        if numbers.count(row) > max_occurance_count:
            max_occurance_count=numbers.count(row)
            max_occured_row = row
print(numbers)
print (max_occured_row)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv

numbers = []

with open('example.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        numbers.append(row)    

a = [] #empty list
for i in numbers:
    a.append(numbers.count(i))   
numbers[a.index(max(a))]
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 5, 6, 8, 45, 56]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use Counter, you can do the following (l is your list):

```
d={tuple(i):l.count(i) for i in l}
d=sorted(d, key=lambda x: d[x], reverse=True)

res=list(d[0])

print(res)

#[1, 5, 6, 8, 45, 56]
```